# How to allow specified user to view premium content of specified book in django

Tags: django, django-views

I hope someone can help me. I am a student and a beginner in django. I am trying to allow a certain premium user to view the premium content of a specific book. I already have models for the books, users, and membership type. However, I would like to know how I can connect those 3 so that a certain user can only see just the *ALLOWED PREMIUM CONTENT* of *ONE* specific book coming from a list of books.

Here's the code sample:

class Book(models.Model):

```
code = models.SlugField(unique=True, help_text="Enter BIC Code", null=True)
title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
author = models.ForeignKey('Author', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
artist = models.ForeignKey('Artist', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

summary = models.TextField(max_length=1000, help_text="Enter a brief description of the book")
book_type = models.ForeignKey('Type', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
isbn = models.CharField('ISBN', max_length=15, help_text='Enter ISBN number')

status = models.CharField(choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='Ongoing', null=True, max_length=30)
genre = models.ManyToManyField(Genre, help_text="Select a genre for this book")
language = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True,
                            help_text="Enter the book's natural language (e.g. English, Tagalog, Japanese etc.)")

released_date = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, help_text="Enter the Released Date (e.g. March 2014)")
cover = models.ImageField(upload_to='book_cover', null=True, validators=[img_file_extension],
                          help_text="Image File Only")

teaser = models.FileField(upload_to='book_preview', validators=[pdf_file_extension], help_text="PDF File Only")
featured = models.BooleanField(null=True, default=False)

timestamp = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)


def display_genre(self):
    return ', '.join([genre.name for genre in self.genre.all()[:3]])

display_genre.short_description = 'Genre'

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('book-detail',  args=[str(self.id)])

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

class Page(models.Model):

```
book = models.ForeignKey('Book', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
file = models.FileField(upload_to='book_content', validators=[pdf_file_extension], help_text="PDF File Only")


def __str__(self):
    return self.book.title

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('page-detail',  kwargs={'id', self.id})
```

class Membership(models.Model):

```
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
title = models.ManyToManyField(Book)
premium = models.BooleanField(default=False)
reference = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True)




def __str__(self):
    return self.user.username
```

i don't know what to do after in views.py

```
class PageDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.View):

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    book = get_object_or_404(Book)
    page = get_object_or_404(Page)
    membership = get_object_or_404(Membership, user=request.user)
    context={'object': None}

    if #-----------------------


    return render(request, "catalog/page_detail.html", context)
```

Comment: Is Membership supposed to be a join table (between user and account type) or a table that describes the account type? In any case your question is very broad and there are too many issues to address here, but the basic idea is you check the user type or the user permissions (eg., user.membership.premium == True) and in response you can redirect the view or show a different version of the page. Have you read the docs? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/#limiting-access-to-logged-in-users-that-pass-a-test